# I want to use vbhtml editor (only the editor not the full razor) in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core, razor

I need to use vbhtml files with editor support in a VB.NET ASP.NET Core project. I don't need Razor to do any thing with these files. Just want the editor support (currently, the editor supports the html part only, not vb code). Is there a reference or a Nuget that I include in the project to borrow vbhtml editor from ASP.NET 5 to ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible. The Razor version which is used by ASP.NET Core MVC does not support the Visual Basic language (e.g. `.vbhtml` files), only C# is supported.

Comment: I am not asking about Razor. I created VB.NET ASP.NET Core apps here:https://github.com/VBAndCs/Vazor-DotNetCore2

Comment: I want to add vbhtml file to the project. I can do so, but the editor deals with the HTML parts only.  My question: can we tell VS.NET to use the vbhtml editor from MVC 5?. Can it be separated as dll (.NET standard) and used?